# How to show boot messages in 14.10?

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I am trying to show the boot messages but all I get is an almost black screen until I see the login manager.

- I removed *quiet* and *splash*
- I removed *quiet* and *splash* and added *noplymouth*
- I removed *quiet* and *splash* and added *nomodeset verbose*

Nothing happened. Is there any configuration I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enable the "normal" text start up edit the "/etc/default/grub" and set the option as below

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

After editing the file, you need your grup to reflect the new changes,

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work when I edited the cmd line interactively while booting. You way works. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, that doesn't "fix" anything. no plymouth === no boot messages. Removing *quiet* will get the kernel to spew messages, but upstart sends everything to plymouth. Generally, what plymouth eventually says happened long, LONG ago. (boot with *--verbose* and you'll see exactly what upstart is doing that plymouth isn't telling you.)